# How to detect a white document (or a card) on a white background (opencv)

Tags: android, opencv

I am currently using opencv and android .

The opencv function "findContours" returns the detected contours only for a white  document on a darker background .

whereas for white document on a white(or lighter) background it does not detect anything .

Could anyone please suggest a way to do this in android using opencv .

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

> The opencv function "findContours" returns the detected contours only
>   for a white document on a darker background .

This is not accurate. According to the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) `findContours(...)` "Finds contours in a binary image".

Therefore you'll need to *binarize* your image first, either using a threshold or a more sophisticated approach. There are nice tutorials on this matter, like [this one](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html). Though many of them are for the C++ API, most of OpenCV methods have counterparts in java.

Comment: is grayscaling a image also binarizing an image ? If so i have grayscalled my image before canny and findcontour

Comment: No, it's not the same. Take a look at the the tutorials.